# How to Retain the indent of an XDocument between a load and save?

Tags: xml, xdoc

I have a XDocument that is formatted like this:

```xml
<tag1><innertag Name="sample">This is text</innertag></tag1>
```

After load and save it changes to the below format:

```xml
<tag1>
   <innertag Name="sample">This is text</innertag>
</tag1>
```

How do I retain the above format?

If I use `SaveOptions` during save, there is nil indent and the whole file is in a single line. I want the above format to be retained. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

`XDocument` object has several `.Save()` method overloads, half of which take [`SaveOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.saveoptions) enum value as the second parameter. This enum probably has what you need:

```cs
public enum SaveOptions
{
    /// <summary>Format (indent) the XML while serializing.</summary>
    None,
    /// <summary>Preserve all insignificant white space while serializing.</summary>
    DisableFormatting,
    /// <summary>Remove the duplicate namespace declarations while serializing.</summary>
    OmitDuplicateNamespaces
}
```